# how shall i transpose rows into new columns only if duplicates appears in rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need to get output like this:

[image]

I tried to use transposing, but I am not getting someone please give idea to do this.

Creation script for table:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (
    itemid int,
    pack int,
    UOM nvarchar(2)
)

INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES
(1,1,'EA'),
(1,10,'BX'),
(1,100,'CA'),
(2,1,'EA'),
(2,10,'RL')
```

Comment: i need to write a query, the output must be like second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select itemid,
max(case when seq = 1 then pack end) pack1,  max(case when seq = 1 then uom end)uom1,max(case when seq = 2 then pack end) pack2, max(case when seq = 2 then uom end) uom2,
  max(case when seq = 3 then pack end) pack3, max(case when seq = 3 then uom end) uom3
from 
(
  select itemid, pack, uom, row_number() over(partition by itemid order by itemid) seq from T1
) d
group by itemid
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL and some pivoting:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @columns nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = (
    SELECT DISTINCT  ','+QUOTENAME('pack' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY itemid) as nvarchar(max)))+','+
            QUOTENAME('UOM'+ cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY itemid) as nvarchar(max)))
    FROM #T1
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  itemid,
            Items+rn as Items,
            [Values]
    FROM (
        SELECT  itemid,
                CAST(UOM as nvarchar(max)) as UOM,
                CAST(pack as nvarchar(max)) as pack,
                CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as nvarchar(max)) as rn
        FROM #T1
        ) as t
    UNPIVOT (
        [Values] FOR Items in ([UOM],[pack])
    ) as up
    ) t1
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR Items IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
itemid  pack1   UOM1    pack2   UOM2    pack3   UOM3
1       1       EA      10      BX      100     CA
2       1       EA      10      RL      NULL    NULL
```

**EDIT#1**

There is one more way:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @columns nvarchar(max),
        @colsrn nvarchar(max)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY itemid) as nvarchar(max)) as rn
FROM #T1
)

SELECT @columns = (
    SELECT ',MAX('+QUOTENAME('pack' + rn) +') as '+ QUOTENAME('pack' + rn) +',MAX('+
            QUOTENAME('UOM'+ rn) +') as ' + QUOTENAME('UOM'+ rn)
    FROM cte
    FOR XML PATH('')
),
        @colsrn = (
    SELECT DISTINCT  ',CASE WHEN rn = ' + rn +' THEN '+QUOTENAME('pack')+' ELSE NULL END as [pack'+rn+'],' 
                    +'CASE WHEN rn = ' + rn +' THEN '+QUOTENAME('UOM')+' ELSE NULL END as [UOM'+rn+']'  
    FROM cte
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT  itemid'+@columns+'
FROM (
    SELECT  itemid'+@colsrn+'
    FROM (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
            FROM #T1
            ) as t
    ) s
GROUP BY s.itemid'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Same output.

Comment: Are you serious? :) the simplest way is to put your table in Excel and pivot there. If the number of packs and UOMs is maximum 3 or 5 you can use query inside `SELECT @sql = N'` and change `'+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+'` to `[pack1],[UOM1],...[packN],[UOMN]` and here it is.

Comment: will you help me to do it by using rowid, select and few cases?

Comment: i am getting error like this "The type of column "pack" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list."

Comment: What is the type of `pack` and `UOM` columns? When UNPIVOTing - there columns must be converted/casted in same datatype. I used `int` for `pack` and `nvarchar(max)` for `UOM` when created temp table and as you can see I am `CAST(pack as nvarchar(max)) as pack,` in the UNPIVOT part.

Comment: In the inner select list instead `UOM` use `CAST(UOM as nvarchar(max)) UOM`. That should solve conflict.

Comment: @Naveen I add solution with no pivoting. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need simple, fixed column solution, you can use:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM
(VALUES 
    (1, 1, 'EA'),
    (1, 10, 'BX'),
    (1, 100, 'CA'),
    (2, 1, 'EA'),
    (2, 10, 'RL')) T(ItemId, Pack, UOM)

SELECT ItemId, MAX([1]) Pack1, MAX([U1]) UOM1, MAX([2]) Pack1, MAX([U2]) UOM1, MAX([3]) Pack1, MAX([U3]) UOM1 FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY Pack) PackNum,
        'U'+CONVERT(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY Pack)) UOMNum
    FROM #temp
) T
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Pack) FOR PackNum IN ([1], [2], [3])
) PPack
PIVOT
(
    MAX(UOM) FOR UOMNum IN ([U1],[U2],[U3])
) PUOM
GROUP BY ItemId
```

If number of columns is not fixed, you must do it dynamically (see @gofr1) or:

```
DECLARE @count TABLE(N varchar(10))
    INSERT @count
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)))
    FROM #temp WHERE ItemId =
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 ItemId
        FROM #temp
        GROUP BY ItemId
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    )

DECLARE @select varchar(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT ', MAX(['+N+']) Pack'+N+', MAX([U'+N+']) UOM'+N FROM @count FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
DECLARE @pivot1 varchar(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT ', ['+N+']' FROM @count FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
DECLARE @pivot2 varchar(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT ', [U'+N+']' FROM @count FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX) = '
SELECT ItemId, '+@select+' FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY Pack) PackNum,
        ''U''+CONVERT(varchar(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY Pack)) UOMNum
    FROM #temp
) T
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Pack) FOR PackNum IN ('+@pivot1+')
) PPack
PIVOT
(
    MAX(UOM) FOR UOMNum IN ('+@pivot2+')
) PUOM
GROUP BY ItemId'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest me without using pivot, how shall i acieve it?